# Trouble understanding surjective function proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic

I'm studying for my discrete math exam and I'm having some trouble understanding this practice problem and solution. I know what surjective functions are, but I can't really understand the way this trait is proved in this example, especially the purpose of the ending exist statement. Could someone translate the steps to plain English for me?

```
3. Let f:A->B be a function. Show, by direct inference, that 
       (Exist g:B->A, All y in B, f.g(y) = y) => (f is surjective)

Sol:
 y in B
=> {All y in B, f.g(y) = y}
 f.g(y) = y
=> {Definition of "."}
 f(g(y)) = y
=> {Let x be the element g(y) in A}
 Exist x in A, f(x) = y
```

Thanks.

Comment: The answers below should satisfy you. I would like to point out that the following are true, and you should spend some time proving and understanding them. They are quite useful. A function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is surjective if and only if $f\circ f^{-1} = \operatorname{Id}_B$. A function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is injective if and only if $f^{-1}\circ f = \operatorname{Id}_A$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f:A\to B$, and suppose that $g:B\to A$ is such that for all $y\in B$, $f(g(y)) = y$. We want to show $f$ is surjective. So choose $y\in B$, and consider $g(y)\in A$. Since $f(g(y)) = y$ by hypothesis, $g(y)$ is an element of $A$ whose image is $y$, so that $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Rather plain english:

We have $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$ with the property that for any $y \in B,$ $(f\circ g)(y) = y$ holds. Recall that $(f\circ g)(y) = f(g(y)),$ that's just notation.

Now we want to show that $f$ is surjective. To this end, we pick an arbitrary $y \in B$ and have to produce an $x\in A$ such that $f(x) = y.$ But since we have $g$ with the special property, thats quite easy. We just put $x := g(y) \in A$ and verify $f(x) = f(g(y)) = y,$ as desired.